# Вопрос по gulp-sass

Tags: html, css, gulp, sass, scss

При использовании плагина gulp-sass, обнаружил что сжатия выходного файла css, а именно compact и nested, перестали поддерживаться? Почему? Это связано с обновлениями?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас gulp sass 5.0?

Comment: да, точно, все верно

Comment: есть подозрение, что это из-за отсутствия поддержки node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Замени 'compact' на 'compressed'.

```
.pipe(scss({ outputStyle: 'compressed' })
```

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.